# Typescript automatic type conversion during the JSON parsing?

Tags: typescript, casting, type-conversion

I have following JSON array where the id key is a string (huh).

```
 "locations": [
    {
      "default_currency_id": "17",
      "continent": "1",
      "country_code": "AL",
      "gift_value": "150",
      "alert": "TEST",
      "caption": "Albania",
      "id": "1"
    },
```

I would like to use automatic conversion based on the value defined in the model instead of the using Number function (see please attached snippet): How is it possible in the right way please? Ideally I would like to put json Array into typed model without manual parsing (as you can see in for loop)

```
    export class Location {
      default_currency_id: number;
      continent: string;
      country_code: string;
      gift_value: string;
      alert: string;
      caption: string;
      id: number;
    }

parseDataset(data: any) {
    console.log('parseDataset');
    console.log(data);

    if(data.locations_gifts != null) {
      //this.dataSet.locations = data.locations_gifts;
      for(let o of data.locations_gifts){//HOW TO AVOID MANUAL PARSING?
        console.log(o);
        let item: Location = <Location>{
          default_currency_id: Number(o.default_currency_id), //HOW TO AVOID MANUAL CONVERSION?
        };
        this.dataSet.locations.push(item);
      }

    }
    console.log(this.dataSet)
  }
```

Comment: Even though your JSON is stringified, you need to convert the ID manually because it is coming as a string. i.e., Had the id been coming "default_currency_id": 17, this way, you would not have to convert but as the id is coming with a string, you need to convert

Comment: Yes, but i asked for some way to apply automatically policy defined in the model?(I do not have access to modify source Json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. TypeScript helps you to verify your code in development, not in the runtime. So data conversion of the dynamic response data is not in its scope (at least until this moment)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the `reviver` option from JSON.parse()
I use it to cast my JSON date (which are string) into Javascript Date objects
exemple here : 
https://mariusschulz.com/blog/deserializing-json-strings-as-javascript-date-objects

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using a signature in your code like this:

```
const sign = {
  default_currency_id: "integer",
  continent: "string",
  country_code: "string",
  gift_value: "string",
  alert: "string",
  caption: "string",
  id: "integer"
}

parseDataset(data: any) {
  console.log(data);
  let dataDecoded:any = {};
  Object.keys(this.sign).forEach((key, index) => {

    let value = data[index];

    if (value) {
      switch (this.sign[key]) {
        case 'integer': 
          value = parseInt(value);
          break;

        default: value = value.toString();
      }

      dataDecoded[key] = value;
    }
  });
}
```